# Accessing a character pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* output;
int main() {
output="Hello";
output[0]='r'; // This line shows error . Please assist as to why 
printf(output);
return 0;
}
```

Please tell the correct way to do so . I know this might be a stupid question for most of the people , but I wanted to perform an operation like this (the line with comment ) ,so this is just a short example of the problem that i am facing.

Thank You

Comment: String literals are immutable. Use `char output[6];` and `strcpy` instead

Comment: UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR!!

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
output = "Hello";
```

Then char pointer `output` points to a `string`. By their very nature `strings` are immutable objects.

Comment: **string** should be **string literal**.